# Improve custom comparator code quality

Tags: java, software-quality

Any better way to write this comparator?

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = (op1,op2) -> {
         Integer id1 = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(op1.get(field)));
         Integer id2 = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(op2.get(field)));
         return id2.compareTo(id1);
         };
```

Is it possible to avoid the two `valueOf`?

Comment: It doesn't ask a specific question, or indicate any real problems with the existing code. Asking to make code "better" without a specific goal/metric to use is almost always closed as opinion based.

Comment: What is the `JSONObject` class? From which package?

Comment: http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html#writeJSONString(java.io.Writer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `Comparator.comparingInt`

You should be able to do the following:

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = 
    Comparator.comparingInt(obj -> Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(obj.get(field))))
    .reversed();
```

#### `getInt`

Check the API of the `JSONObject` to see if there is an `getInt` method or similar on it, then you should be able to use that directly instead of wrapping in `valueOf` calls, such as:

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = Comparator.<JSONObject>comparingInt(obj -> obj.getInt(field))
    .reversed();
```

#### Return type of `.get`

Alternatively, you should investigate what type your `obj.get(field)` returns. If you are lucky, it can be as simply as a typecast:

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = 
    Comparator.<JSONObject>comparingInt(obj -> (Integer) obj.get(field))
    .reversed();
```

#### Return type is `String`

If you are always getting `Strings` as a result from `obj.get`, then you should be able to use `Integer.valueOf` directly, instead of also calling `String.valueOf`

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = 
    Comparator.<JSONObject>comparingInt(obj -> Integer.valueOf(obj.get(field)))
    .reversed();
```

Depending on the API, you still might need to typecase to `String`

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = 
    Comparator.<JSONObject>comparingInt(obj -> Integer.valueOf((String) obj.get(field)))
    .reversed();
```

Comment: Don't get it. Is obj op1 or op2?

Comment: @user3727540 Neither, `Comparator.comparing` gives you a way to specify which *field/value* should be compared on the object, and then it will extract that value for both fields. The call to `.reversed()` in the end is because in your original code you did `id2.compareTo(id1)` instead of `id1.compareTo(id2)`

Comment: JSOObject has only a method get returning an Object.

Comment: @user3727540 Which **package** is the `JSONObject` from?

Comment: @user3727540: assuming you mean Android's [`org.json.JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getInt\(java.lang.String\)), it has a `getInt()` method.

Comment: Got this error with that snippet: The method get(String) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: field is always a string.

Comment: @user3727540 If possible, I'd recommend changing JSON library. My personal preference is to use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). With your current library it does not seem like you can get rid of all the `valueOf` calls.

Comment: Indeed, I got this Type mismatch: cannot convert from Comparator<Object> to Comparator<JSONObject>

Comment: @user3727540 You might need to use `Comparator<JSONObject>.comparingInt` as the Java compiler might not do the type inference correctly.

Comment: Can't do that. Compiler simply refuses to do it.

Comment: @user3727540 Sorry, I meant `Comparator.<JSONObject>comparingInt`

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to avoid the two valueOf?

This depends on whether or not know the type of `field` your are trying to get, ie: is it an `int` or a `string` or either

if it is a guaranteed `int` you can simply do this

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = (op1,op2) -> {
     return Integer.valueOf(op1.get(field)).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(op2.get(field));
};
```

for ascending order

if value is a `string` you can do this

```
Comparator<JSONObject> comparator = (op1,op2) -> {
     return Integer.parseInt((String)op1.get(field)) - Integer.parseInt((String)op2.get(field));
};
```

Comment: According to the OP's comment on my answer, this is the object being used: http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple which does not have `getInt` or `getString` methods.